# Build R Function that intakes a directory where the files are stored and a threshold. And returns correlation

Tags: r, correlation

Given: List of files with Probe readings for Sulfate and Nitrate. File contains 4 columns (`Date`, `Sulfate`, `Nitrate`, `ID`).  `ID` refers to the file name.  which is named after a probe location. i.e. Probe location `11` has File named `011.csv` and has `11` populating the ID column. There are 332 files.
Rows have several `NA` values.
Need function to output correlation between `Nitrate` and `Sulfate` of complete cases for each probe where complete cases are greater than a given threshold (cases in which no `NA`s are found).
The function takes in a directory (where the files are located) and the Threshold (number of complete cases)
Example:

```
cr <- corr("specdata", 400)
head(cr)
```

will output (one output per probe)

```
# [1] -0.01895754 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.07588814  0.76312884 -0.15782860
summary(cr)
##     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
## -0.17623 -0.03109  0.10021  0.13969  0.26849  0.76313
```

Example2:

```
cr <- corr("specdata", 5000)
summary(cr)
```

will output (because no probe has more than 5000 complete samples

```
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##
```

I have the following code that calculates the correlation for all the probes, but I don't know how to code in the threshold and have it output in a vector that outputs an individual correlation for each probe location.

```
corr <- function(directory, thresh)  {
     setwd(directory)
     filevector3 <- list.files()
     megadata <- do.call('rbind', lapply(filevector3[1:332], read.csv, header = T))
     cormega <- cor(megadata$sulfate, megadata$nitrate, use = "complete.obs")
     nobs <- c(sum(complete.cases(megadata)))

     return(cormega)
}
```

Comment: In your function you compute `nobs` but do not return it. Do you want to return it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following function does what you want.
It's difficult to say if it does because there is no data to test the function.

```
corr <- function(directory, thresh)  {
  f <- function(filename, thresh){
    dat <- read.csv(filename)
    inx <- complete.cases(dat)
    val <- if(sum(inx) >= thresh)
      with(dat[inx, ], cor(sulfate, nitrate))
    else
      NA
    c(value = val, id = dat$ID[1])
  }

  old_dir <- setwd(directory)
  on.exit(setwd(old_dir))

  files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv", ignore.case = TRUE)
  res <- lapply(files, f, thresh = thresh)
  do.call(rbind, res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. Here it is. maybe there is a better way without doing two loops, but I'm new to this.

```
   for(i in 1:332) {
          compdata <- read.csv(filevector2[i])
          nobs <- c(nobs, sum(complete.cases(compdata)))
     }

     nobs  # here I returned the nobs, just to make sure that part was working right

     ## loop below populates corrvect vector with all the correlation coeff for each probe that meets threshold 
     ## requirements indicated in the if statement.
     for(j in 1:332) {
          minicomp <- read.csv(filevector2[j])
          if (nobs [j] > thresh) {
               corrvect <- c(corrvect, cor(minicomp$sulfate, minicomp$nitrate, use = "complete.obs"))

      }

 } 

 corrvect # here I returned the corrvect
```

}